# React Native And CSV's is it possible?

Tags: node.js, react-native, csv, crud

So I am working on a react native project and up until now my projects database were two simple variables its the truth.
And here they are:

```
// const all of the tasks to do
const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);
// const all the selected Tasks
const [selectedTasks, setSelectedTasks] = useState([]);
```

The problem with this is that every time i close the app and reopen it, all the data resets
and that is why I have now decided to finally add a database in the form of a csv file, only problem I cant find a react native module that helps me do that. I need a react native or npm module that can create, update, read all the data from the my app to a csv file.

Answer (score 0):

Creating your own data storage isn't a good idea imo, you should have a look at [AsyncStorage](https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage). You might be able to easily rework your app to use it and there is plenty of thread about it on internet and is very easy to use. As the doc says :

Persisting data (setItem() method) :

```
_storeData = async () => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem(
      '@MySuperStore:key',
      'I like to save it.'
    );
  } catch (error) {
    // Error saving data
  }
};
```

Fetching item (getItem() method) :

```
_retrieveData = async () => {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('TASKS');
    if (value !== null) {
      // We have data!!
      console.log(value);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // Error retrieving data
  }
};
```

I'll let you have a look at all the other possibilities !

Comment: Maybe but A final goal on the database for this app was that it be sent on google drive and a mentor of mine suggested that I put the file in such a format that even a non programmer would understand the data so in that sense is AsyncStorage useful?

Comment: @KidCoder AsyncStorage help to persist data as string, so you can still save objects, and when you need to push it on a cloud, use `JSON.stringify()` to get a json. Now if you need a CSV, there is tools that help you convert it as CSV, such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-json-to-csv. Now it depend on what you want to do, it still works well with a database